# Consolidate different variables to one variable

Tags: stata

I've got several different variables that describe the size of an aneurysm. There's a variable for each location the aneurysm can be in, so it's `sizeInLocation1`, `sizeInLocation2`, etc.

I would like to make a new variable called `size` equal to whatever `sizeInLocation`X is.

I could manually do this by

```
replace size = sizeInLocation1
```

if 1 is where the size was. That's too tedious and I would have to find out which location the aneurysm was in first. How can I do a `replace` that takes whichever of selected variables has a field?

Comment: Explain the downvote, please.

Comment: I didn't downvote. Whoever did was, I guess,  not impressed by  the lack of a reproducible data example or of much attempt to find out suitable code, or even by lack of formatting. I am guessing; it wasn't me. SO is collectively ambiguous about supporting rank beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your variables are numeric, then

```
egen wanted = rowmean(sizeInLocation*)
```

will take the mean. As that ignores missing values, it will return the single value wanted that is non-missing. `rowmin()`, `rowmax()` and yet other `egen` functions will do the same thing.

There is a case for using `rowmin()` and `rowmax()` and checking that the results are the same, which is guaranteed if there is just one non-missing value in the variables in question in each observation. (It will also be true if all values are missing or two or more non-missing values are present but equal.)